# GIT: What happens if I push a branch which is not the current branch?

Tags: git

Sometimes when working within a git repository, I will be working on a branch which is not "master". Often I will type without thinking `git push origin master`. I assumed this would be a disastrous thing do to, but I am now questioning that assumption.

As far as I can see there are two possibilities as to what happens here. Which is correct?

- The information contained in branch "master" is pushed to origin. It probably was already pushed some time ago before you switched which branch you were working on, so probably nothing will actually happen.
- The information contained in the current branch is pushed to origin/master. (The master branch at the location origin.) This would be a bad thing to happen because you would over-write your master branch on origin, which would presumably create a lot of confusion if someone else tried to "pull" origin/master!

I had for a long time assumed the second option was what happened, however after thinking about this, it would seem much more sensible behaviour if the first option is what happens.

I now think that the first option is correct, am I right?

Comment: It's quite easy to try. Create the remote locally in a different directory and try yourself to see.

Comment: Explained in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push-ltrefspecgt82308203): "missing :<dst> means to update the same ref as the <src>."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, first option is correct.

If you want to push current branch to master branch on origin, then use

git push origin HEAD:master

Comment: In what sort of situation would someone want to do this? Is it not a bit of a hazardous thing to do, as the current branch might be completely different to master?

Comment: @user3728501 - Why you would do it, and whether it's hazardous, both depend on how the repo is configured and what sort of workflow is being used.  In a default configuration with a typical project, there's not a lot of reason you'd do it.  But also, in a default configuration, it's not really hazardous, because git would reject a push that doesn't preserve the existing history (unless given a `--force` option; the `--force` option can be a problem if misused).